# What is the significance of AdMob test device?

Tags: android, admob

I could see there is some test id for testing the AdMob ads in Android devices. I know how to get the test id from log cat.

What is the difference in testing the ads in Android devices with the statement `adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");` and without it? Because on both the scenarios I am able to get the ads without any problem.

The code:

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By doing this, you would be loading test ads on your device/emulator.

This is good, since, many times, you might tap on the adverts by mistake, and your account could be banned if this happens regularly or if Admobs decides that you are making those taps deliberately to increase your revenue.

**From the docs:**

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting#adrequest

> Requesting test ads is recommended when testing your application so
>   you do not request invalid impressions. In addition, you can always
>   count on a test ad being available.

Comment: So if I don't press the ads, can I still use my own app or am I completely banned from using my app with ads?

Comment: Adding ad impressions while testing might also be seen as an abuse, but I am not sure.

Comment: how does admob decide that the device is a test device, for e.g. I used a device for debugging, now I want to install the real app on it, is the device still counted as a test device?

Comment: Be sure to remove the code that sets these test device IDs before you release your app so it is better to write such code in control statement  if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) { adRequest.addTestDevice("3E4409D3BCF2XXXXX5D87F53CD4XXXXX");}

Answer (score 5):

"TEST_DEVICE_ID" is just a placeholder for your device unique ID.
It should be replaced with something like:

```
adRequest.addTestDevice("3E4409D3BCF2XXXXX5D87F53CD4XXXXX");
```

To find your device ID: Run your app with `adRequest.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID");` in your code, this would print your device ID to the log. Search the logcat trace for an INFO message containing the text:

```
adRequest.addTestDevice
```

Comment: If i am install the real app on device, is the device still consider as a test device? @Gili Nachum

Comment: App packaging shouldn't affect the detection of a test device, that happens by id.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice(Device.getId(this))
        .build();
```

The Device class:

```
public class Device {

    public static String getId(Context context) {
        String deviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        try {
            MessageDigest digest = java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            digest.update(deviceId.getBytes());
            byte messageDigest[] = digest.digest();

            StringBuffer hexString = new StringBuffer();
            for (int i = 0; i < messageDigest.length; i++) {

                String h = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[i]);

                while (h.length() < 2)
                    h = "0" + h;

                hexString.append(h);
            }

            deviceId = hexString.toString();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            deviceId = "";
        } finally {
            return deviceId.toUpperCase();
        }
    }
}
```